# $p$-adic lifts of tropical varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

What is currently known about lifts of tropical varieties to varieties over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or its extensions?  Starting with an appropriate rational polyhedral cone complex what are the obstructions to its deformation to a (toric or log-smooth) variety over a $p$-adic field classified by? In which major cases are they known to vanish? What are the corresponding deformation spaces?

Summary and references would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are moduli spaces of tropical lifts. They satisfy "Murphy's law": Any behavior which can happen on a scheme of finite type can happen on them. See Katz and Payne "[Realization spaces for tropical fans](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4582)" for the details.